# Adaptive parameter in ECJ

Tags: ecj

I’m going to use ecj in eclipse for adaptive ecfor example ga, and I need to change parametere’s value such as mutation probability during the execution, ( I still have defined a value in .params file but need to update during execution) I don’t know how to that! Can anyone help

Comment: To me your goal is not clear: what is "ecfor", what is "ga"? If you want to change a parameter during execution, what roles does ecj (a compiler) have in that picture? What parameters do you want to change?

Comment: Note, that the tag `ecj` refers to the "Eclipse Compiler for Java". Since Eclipse is mentioned in the question, the relation to ecj looked plausible, but it just occurred to me that ECJ may also be the name of an unrelated framework. If that's what you mean please remove the tag "ecj".